# Time series structural analysis with R's strucchange package: Interpreting breakpoint dating with respect to breakpoint testing

Tags: regression, time-series, structural-change

I am working with a short time series consisting of 21 annual observations,  and I want to detect structural breaks using the strucchange package (Zeileis et al. 2002).

[image]

When I run the breakpoints() function to date an optimum number of breakpoints chosen by BIC, I get 3 breakpoints occurring at locations that make sense with respect to exogenous information I have about my system.

[image]

When I run sctest.efp(), though, I do not get any sufficiently extreme values of the empirical fluctuation process to identify statistically significant breakpoints.

[image]

When I run sctest.Fstats(), which tests for just a single breakpoint, I get a highly significant peak corresponding to one of the breakdates identified by breakpoints().

[image]

I'm confused by how to interpret these results.

1. Is the nonsignificance of sctest.efp vs. the significance of sctest.Fstats due to the shortness of my time series and the corresponding lack of statistical power for detecting multiple breakpoints?
2. Can the optimal breakpoints identified by breakpoints() be legitimately interpreted with respect to exogenous information apart from finding formal significance using sctest()? In other words, does BIC support for > 0 breakpoints constitute statistical support for structural change despite negative results in sctest(), or should I instead interpret the results of breakpoints() as mere putative breakpoints pending the results of sctest()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different tests have different power properties for different patterns of structural changes. The supF test has been designed for single abrupt shifts but also has good power for many other patterns. The Recursive-CUSUM test, on the other hand, works only well for single shifts occurring early in the sample. The latter is not the case and hence the Rec-CUSUM is not significant. Using an OLS-CUSUM instead would surely yield a significant result as well.

Thus, the tests can be used to show that the mean (aka the level) of your time series is not constant over the full sample. However, you didn't need a significance test to reject that null hypothesis - it's clearly not a plausible null model.

I'm not sure what would work best here or what would be a plausible model to hold within each segment. Potentially, taking logs would yield a pattern for which a piecewise linear curve would fit...